# When I search on a space, why does one SQL Server 2017 instance return results and the other instance doesn't?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

My DEV Server is SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.1000.169).

My STAGING Server is SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.2027.2).

My DEV server returns results when I run the following. My STAGING server does not

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm varchar(32) = ' ', @tmID numeric = 200

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE [Active] = 0
  AND [Deleted] = 0
  AND [MyID] NOT IN (SELECT [MyID_FK]
                     FROM [dbo].[Table2]
                     WHERE [Test_FK] = @tmID)
  AND ([FirstField] LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
       OR [SecondField] LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
       OR [ThirdField] LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%')
```

My STAGING server does return results if `@SearchTerm = ''` instead of `@SearchTerm = ' '` < There is a space in the last one

I've gone through all of the options for both servers making sure they are identical

Comment: Is the `DECLARE` not part of the code section?

Comment: Do both servers have the same ANSI_PADDING setting?

Comment: @shawnt00 - Yes, they are both the same

Comment: Does the data come from the same backup? Have you identified a single row in question to look at individual values?

Comment: #shawn00 - Yes it does. I can also duplicate the issue with T-SQL using MSSMS